# Executing AsyncTask before the following code

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem and it's that I have a `bundle` in which I pass some info. The problem it's that the info that I get it's being retrieved from an `AsyncTask` and I need to execute it before the values will be set on the `bundle`.

This part of code resumes what happens:

```
String name = "";
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

new findCar(new OnCarListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCarCompleted(String c) {

        synchronized (c) 
        {
            name = c;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCarError(String error) {
    }
}).execute(idCar);

Log.d("AsyncTask", "AsyncTask completed");  
Log.d("AsyncTask", name);
bundle.putString(name);
```

And the lines that are below the `AsyncTask` are executed before it. What I need it's to execute the `AsyncTask` before the lines that it has below.

**What I have tried:**

**1)** As you can see in the code that I put above, I created an `interface` and try to `synchronize` the `String` that I pass from `onPostExecute()` method with the objective that it will be executed before the rest of the code, but it doesn't work.

**2)** I saw that you can block the UI Thread with `AsyncTask.get()` but it's not what I'm searching because I don't know how much seconds the `AsyncTask` will need to complete its objective.

**3)** If it is possible I would want to avoid use `ProgressDialog`.

**4)** I also tried to use the `bundle` directly inside `onCarCompleted` but it doesn't store the value into the `bundle`.

**5)** Furthermore, I tried executing the `AsyncTask` with `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,idCar)` but the result was the same.

Is there some option that let me execute the `AsyncTask` **before** the lines of code that are below it? I need to retrieve the info from the database before that setting it on the bundle, and not upside down.

I'm stuck here from hours. Any help will be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just override the onPostExecute() metho in your asyncTask. or am I not undertanding your issue?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin The result it's the same. What I want it's that the `AsyncTask` will be executed before the `Logs` and the `bundle.putString` because until the `AsyncTask` doesn't work `name` doesn't have any value.

Comment: the code below `execute(idCar);` would be executed without waiting `onCarCompleted`, you may create a function to do anything you need after that

Comment: Can someone please explain me what it's wrong in my question for the downvote? I don't care about the rep but I'm intrigued about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why your current attempts have failed (**mostly, you aren't really embracing the asynchronous nature of the problem at hand**):

1) *As you can see in the code that I put above, I created an interface and try to synchronize the String that I pass from onPostExecute() method with the objective that it will be executed before the rest of the code, but it doesn't work.*

This fails for a lot of reasons, but primarily you aren't using synchronization for the correct reasons, and you aren't using it correctly (for example, only one thread is ever synchronizing on the string). Its not the way to go for this one.

4) *I also tried to use the bundle directly inside onCarCompleted but it doesn't store the value into the bundle.*

Actually, it probably does. But whatever you do with the bundle is probably finished by the time the async task has set the value

5) *Furthermore, I tried executing the AsyncTask with .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR,idCar) but the result was the same.*

The SERIAL_EXECUTOR executes async tasks serially, and would have no effect on what you are doing, since you only have **one** async task

What you should probably do is to put more logic into your `onCarCompleted` method. For example:

```
String name = "";
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

new findCar(new OnCarListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCarCompleted(String name) {

        Log.d("AsyncTask", "AsyncTask completed");  
        Log.d("AsyncTask", name);
        bundle.putString(name);
        // do something with the bundle here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCarError(String error) {
    }
}).execute(idCar);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the big explanation! Most of them I supposed why they don't work but I'm really desperate with this and I put here because I saw it in a lot of answers in other questions. But I have a doubt: should I add on my `onCarCompleted` method all the actions including the `startActivity(intent)` function?

Comment: Yes, you should do that

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is async, so when you'll receive the data is unknown.
For that reasons you have your callback. 
Yours 4th solution is correct, but not fully. You should do ALL the things you need to do after you received the result only directly in callback method.

```
private Bundle bundle;

....
bundle = new Bundle();
new findCar(new OnCarListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCarCompleted(String c) {
        processData(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCarError(String error) {
    }
}).execute(idCar);

void processData(String data) {
    bundle.putString(data);
    //Do all you need then
}
```

executeOnExecutor method with SERIAL_EXECUTOR is the same as just execute(), because the default executor of AsyncTasks is SERIAL_EXECUTOR.

Also, why do you synchronized your variable?

Comment: Similar to `nmio` but I accepted his answer because of the extended explanation. +1 for be helpful too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change a little bit like this way below. But I think you should throw this logic and update it: try to run AsyncTask and onPostExecute() do what it need do more to finish your works, it is easier to handle and avoid "before/after" problem.

```
String name = "";
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
final Object lock = new Object();
new findCar(new OnCarListener(){
@Override
public void onCarCompleted(String c) {

    synchronized (c) 
    {
        name = c;
    }
lock.notify();//Unlock caller-thread
}

@Override
public void onCarError(String error) {
}
}).execute(idCar);

lock.wait();// Your current thread will be locked here, code below will not be executed until "lock.notify()" called
bundle.putString(name);
```